# NetworkError: 400 BAD REQUEST ionic framework

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am Integrating push notification.I have Integrated Suceesfully.Only when Problem I am facing that is:

```
"NetworkError: 400 BAD REQUEST - https://apps.ionic.io/api/v1/app/77c3656e/users/identify"
{"error":"You must specify Content-Type: application/json header"}
```

My code is as below:

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
  //$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/javascript";
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
})
```

When I remove

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
```

Then it is working perfectly.But my other web services stops working.Then cross origin problem comes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you use code to change the default content-type application wide, it may interfere with the code Ionic is using in the user service. If I had to guess, I'd say this is something Ionic could fix by specifying a content type for their calls to handle cases like this where people like you change the defaults. I'd file a bug on the Ionic github repo for this.

For now though, your only hope may be to NOT change it at the default level, and instead, set it for your other web service calls. It means a bit more work for you, but it would get it fixed rather quickly.